# Multiple Limit Distance Constraints

Tags: constraints

I will say that I've looked at a question called, "[Distance constraints between objects/vertices/edges](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24033/distance-constraints-between-objects-vertices-edges)," but it didn't help.

I am not sure if this is a known bug or if it is meant to be this way, but when I add two *Limit Distance* constraints to an object (empty), the second negates the effect of the first. I would like it if when the empty translates to the maximum distance between the two objects, the objects stop separating.

For example, I was working on a project to answer a [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53838/moving-arms-in-a-specific-manner-with-two-fixed-points) concerning hinged objects and I had almost everything worked out. For the bottom left joint, connecting the triangle to the bottom bar, I used an empty with *Limited Distance* from the bottom bar and *Limited Distance* from an empty at the left of the top bar (I would *Stretch To* the triangle mesh between the two aforementioned empties). The following is the image the user posted in the second question linked.

[image]

This is the .blend file I was working on:

[image]

Comment: The constraints act in a top to bottom order, when there will be a conflict, the last constraint will always override the previous constraints.

Comment: Is there a way to fix this without python? I've never been a fan of it unless absolutely necessary. @Georges

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm not familiar enough with scripting, but a trick I learned from a tutorial by Rigging genius Nathan Vegdahl (The developer of Rigify addon), whenever you have a complicated relation, increase the count of parents, as in the case when you need to parent two objects to each other in both ways, so each one of them will use a property from the other, and which is awkward and simply not possible, you can use a third family member to be in-between, this simplifies the matter, I hope I was clear enough, but yeah, that's how it is.

Comment: I'm reading your question again, I already answered the question you're referring to, using a different method, but I'm really interested to know the way you're trying to do it, can you plz edit your question to explain more how you're trying to solve it? @shadypuck

Comment: @Georges I have some stuff to do right now, but I will probably be able to add more details tonight. Maybe even screenshots:)